# ADODB.Command error odbc mysql ASP(Classic not .net)

Tags: mysql, odbc

I'm trying to set up an old website on my local windows 10 machine!
I've setup IIS and added the classic ASP module and If I use non database ASP pages
it works fine.  I've installed MySQL and setup ODBC with the proper driver and can access and test
the database fine!
Its when I try access the database via ASP that it fails! The code I'm using worked fine on the web server.

This is the code that gives the error!

```
 Set Recordset1_cmd = Server.CreateObject ("ADODB.Command")
 Recordset1_cmd.ActiveConnection = "DSN=netcode;UID=peter;PSW=1234;"    *** This is the line that fails ***
```

I've also modified the read/write permissions on the INETPUB folder and all subfolders to full control!
And have modifier the users to full control as well!

thanks

Pete

Comment: Check that you use ODBC Administrator 32 bit on your server. ASP Classic runs as 32 bit app

Comment: Yes it is and the driver is MySQL ODBC 5.3 ANSI 32bit Driver and MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode 32bit (tried both).

Answer (score 0):

I had to go to IIS application tools , click on Default appPool and check the enable 32bit applications!

I also had to run in DNS-less mode!   "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.3 ANSI Driver}; Server=127.0.0.1;Database=prestige;User=user1;Password=1234; OPTION=3"

I know this ASP classic is ancient now but I just needed to get a report printed!

Thanks

Pete